# Streamreader problems

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a real noob to C# trying to write a small XML replacer program based on a short code a friend of mine used in one of his apps..

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
```

I get an error: "Empty path name is not legal."
why doesn't this work?

the code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ReplaceMe
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox1.Text.Replace(".", "_new."));
        string cur = "";
        do
        {
            cur = sr.ReadLine();
            cur = cur.Replace(textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(cur);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream);

        sw.Close();
        sr.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Finished, the new file is in the same directory as the old one");
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

    }


}
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A non-related note: you should wrap your streams in a using clause.  This will ensure that Close() is called even if an exception happens.

Comment: also note: avoid doing such functionality in constructor - you end up with errors in designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure the file exists before you try to access it, it seems you deliver an empty string as a filename.

try accessing the file only when:

```
if (File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
{
  //Your Code...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That is because your `textBox1` doesn't contain text at the moment you create `StreamReader`. You set `textBox1` text in `button1_Click`, so you have to create `StreamReader` in that method.

Answer (score 1):

the value of textbox1 is null or empty. also, if you want to manipulate xml look into the objects of the [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace. These objects are designed specifically for working with XML.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're setting an empty string in `StreamReader` constructor.

I recommend you do a simple validation before read file.

as this:

```
 string fileName = textBox1.Text; 
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) {
       //textbox is empty 
    } else if(File.Exists(fileName)) {
      //file not exists
   } else {
     // read it 
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    //..
  }
```

Note: it is not right way to manipulate xml files.
check out the XML [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.